# DNX fails with "Error: The specified path, file name, or both are too long"

Tags: dnx

DNX error:
Error: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified
file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less
than 248 characters.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a problem with a "node_modules" folder, which includes a hell lot of files with a long paths.

Adding "exclude" setting to the root of project.json file solved the problem:

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
```

So you can actually exclude any files causing this issue.

Comment: If you can, upgrade to npm 3. It solves the long paths issue by flattening the modules folder

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has released fix for this long path issue. Please find the post [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/846475/long-paths-causing-errors-in-latest-msbuild-with-l.html) in Developer community.

According to this, need to download latest Visual studio.